# Server request backbone without a Model object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone application I’ve been making changes to. It is a CMS-like system and we maintain a cache on the server to deliver content faster. However, the cache needs to be cleared when new content is added. So, I added a POST method on the server to clear the “cache” on the server. This call just returns HTTP response 200, or 4xx.

I want to make a call to this from my Backbone application, but there is no model associated with “cache”. I understand that all other requests from the app are either `fetch()`, `save()`, `destroy()` on a model. How do I make requests without a model?

PS. I’m new to Backbone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do a jQuery POST without bothering about Backbone

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: I thought of that. But the base URL backbone is using for the requests comes from the `server.js` file. We’re using `node server.js` to start the server. The base URL changes depending on where the server is running. I can't figure out how to get that base URL in the backbone app. Can I upload the `server.js` file somewhere for you to have a quick look?

Comment: the server cannot directly specify a URL for a Backbone model or collection; it has to be set somewhere in the client. figure out where that is and that's where you can get the URL for the post

Comment: Just did a project-wide string search. The only two places the base URL is found is `server.js`. There has to be a way it gets to the Backbone model. The models just have the endpoints, like `/users`. Thats it.

Comment: `window.location` only gives the URL of the current page. Not the URL of the server it connects to.